# Write vectors in one CSV file using VBA

Tags: vba, csv

I want to write three vectors directly in `csv` file as three columns like in the [image: pic]

```
 For l = 1 To AnzahlPfade Step stepSize 
        offset = (l - 1) * anzahlJahre + 1
.
.
.

            moAkt(l) = zaktie
            moImmo(l) = zImmo
            moShort(l) = zshort


    Next l
```

How is it possible?

Now, I am generating a sheet and save the sheet as csv

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Randomnum").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\to.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

But it is not a really good approach in the case that I go through a loop to generate 1000 times the sheet, save and remove it.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to go via a temporary sheet, the CSV file format is really simple, you can always directly [open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx) the output file as text and [write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264524.aspx) in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem!